# angular formatting datetime string into readable format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm getting this back from my API: 2016-09-08T00:07:34.65. I want it in a more readable format, such as Sep 8, 2016 7:34 AM.

Two issues:

1] All the compact JS date() examples seem to format for date only, no time unless it's super-long.

2] The angular examples seems to involve multiple lines of code, meaning I'll have to move it out of a one-line template and into a service. I'd like to do it in as compact a way as reasonable, since this is within a GRID template, like this:

```
columns: [
    { 
        title: "Date Created", 
        template: "#: DateCreated | #" 
    }
]
```

To use multiple lines of code, I'll end up doing this:

```
        template: function(item){
            return dateTimeService.formatDateTime(item.DateCreated) 
        }
```

Comment: Does the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) not work for you?

Comment: I guess the grid's template interpolation interferes with Angular's interpolation : template: "{{ #:DateCreated#  | date : format : timezone }}" doesn't work.

Comment: `$filter('date')(item.DateCreated, 'MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a')` will return the date formatted exactly as you need it. Can you not use it after getting the API response and before preparing the grid? I'm missing that part.

Comment: Ah! I was so busy concentrating on doing it as a template, I didn't think of doing it as a function: **template:  function(item) {return $filter('date')(item.DateCreated, 'MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a')}** (needs a return in there.) Thanks! How do I 'Mark as Answer' a comment?